# How to set focus on <input type="text" /> on "SelectedIndexChange" event of an DevExpress combobox at client click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function DefaultText(textBox) {
    textBox.focus(function()
    {
        if ($(this).val() == $(this)[0].title)
        {
            $(this).removeClass("activecss");
            $(this).val("");
        }
    });

    textBox.blur(function()
    {
        if ($(this).val() == "")
        {
            $(this).addClass("deactivatecss");
            $(this).val($(this)[0].title);
        }
    });    
    textBox.blur();
}
```

---

Above function is called when document loaded successful.

### form.aspx

```
       <dx:ASPxComboBox ID="comboBoxAttributes" SelectedIndexChanged="function(s, e) { $('#textBox').focus(); }" />
        </dx:ASPxComboBox>
```

now it got focus for mili sec. and then goes to ASPxComboBox's selected text.

Answer (score 2):

<s>Bind a click event to your button and call .focus() to trigger a focus event:</s>

Bind a change event on your dropdown and call .focus() to trigger a focus event:

```
$('#dropdown').change(function() { 
     $('#textbox').focus();
});
```

Note: replace "#dropdown" and "#textbox" by selectors to your dropdown and your textbox respectively.

Further reading:

- [Bind a change event](http://api.jquery.com/change/)
- [.focus()](http://api.jquery.com/focus/)

Comment: same is for this: textbox gets focus but due to above code it loos focus within milisec and shows default text.

Comment: Well, you are triggering a blur event in you function `DefaultText()`. When do you call this function ?

Comment: within $(document).ready(function(){ DefaultText($("#textBox")); })

Comment: you are right it is working with button but i forget to update question actually now i want to set focus when i select an item from a dropdownbox. I have updated question.

Comment: Bind a "change" event on the dropdown.

Comment: please elaborate little bit more.

Comment: I thought you would be able to go to the documentation of jquery I've linked and try figuring out yourself, it is so trivial... anyway, I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="button" id="button" value="Button"/>

$("#button").click(function(){
      textBox.trigger("focus");     
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use the below line to focus particular text box

```
$("#button").click(function(){

      $("#id").focus();or $('.classname').focus();    
});
```

Comment: textbox gets focus but due to above code it loos focus within milisec and shows default text.